# Who am I? Look at the images and deduce my identity

Tags: riddle, visual

Can you deduce who I am using these pictures?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I bet it's _gur uhyx_.

Comment: @a.mahrir, in case you are wondering what all the downvotes are for, it's because this puzzle is very trivial. kedarguru and I were both able to solve it within a matter of seconds, and I imagine most users also will. (I didn't downvote, btw.) Try not to be discouraged, but do also have a look at some of the other puzzles on the site to see the kind of standard we're looking for. And try not to go the other way and make your next puzzle too difficult!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> The Hulk.

Reasoning:

> He’s a regular human (Bruce Banner), but when he’s angry he turns green.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> The Incredible Hulk

And "how you are" is

> Angry

Explanation:

> The first image is of an ordinary human, which is what Bruce Banner is. The second image is of anger, which is the requirement for Bruce to transform into the Hulk. The third image is of the colour green, which is the Hulk's skin colour.

Comment: Beaten by about a minute :P